# Using wildcard in host attribute for android 12 AppLinks does not work ( android:host="*.example.com" does not work but www.example.com does )

Tags: android, deep-linking, mobile-development, applinks

If I use a wildcard to define deeplinking in Android 12 does not work it fails with `legacy_failure` if I run `pm get-app-links com.example.app` in `adb shell` but if I use a specific domain, the it works. So if I use

`<data android:host="*.example.com" android:pathPrefix="/profile/" />`

it gives me `legacy_failure`

but if I use

`<data android:host="www.example.com" android:pathPrefix="/profile/" />`

it works fine, and verifies. Wildcard usage should be possible based on documentation, and it worked in previous versions ( if I fun my app on a device with < 12 version of android it works just fine )

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations#multi-subdomain

I need to catch every subdomain, because we have a lot for this project - any idea how can I overcome this is much appreciated :)

( I made sure that everything from https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations is correct )

Comment: Are you sure that [your `assetlinks.json` is served without redirects](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171819080)?

Comment: THIS ^ Thanks @CommonsWare , that was the problem - I've been looking at the documentation for hours, and missed that. Kudos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `assetlinks.json` file [is supposed to be served directly, without redirects](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations#publish-json). Apparently, in some scenarios, the redirect is OK, but not in other scenarios. Somebody else [ran into the same problem as you](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171819080), and the redirect was the culprit.